# Why isn't the letter final char ('g') printed?

Tags: c, for-loop, decrement

I know that the first letters printed are b c d e f. Why is 'g' not printed? when I is 5, 'f' is printed. The i is decremented to 4 so it should enter the for loop. Instead it doesn't enter despite i being less than 6 (strlen(arr)-1=6).

```
char* arr = "abcdefg";  //String
int i;
for (i = 1; i < strlen(arr)-1; i+=2)  //i is incremented by 2.
{
    printf("%c ", arr[i--]);    //Here i is decremented
}
```

return 0;

Comment: This is just messing around.

Comment: i=5, then i-- makes it 4, then i+=2 makes it 6, then the for loop doesn't execute again because i is 6.

Comment: debugger comes in handy here.

Comment: The loop control variable belongs to the loop itself, and you should not alter it inside the loop. If you do foolish things, expect foolish results.

Comment: Apart from fiddling with the control variable, `i < strlen(arr)-1;` will miss the last character, should be `i < strlen(arr);`

Comment: this wasn't something I wrote. It was on a test and we were arguing about what it prints. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

that's a logic issue, I'll try to illustrate that

---

```
1º loop -> i = 1, arr[--i] = a

2º loop -> i = 3, arr[--i] = c

3º loop -> i = 5, arr[--i] = e
```

end of loop `// i = 7, strlen(arr)-1 = 5`

---

> Note: I didn't debug that in C, but as I said, this is a logic
>   issue...

I think that it's a good idea to try to debugate that with your IDE when this kind of thing happen

Answer (score 0):

In for loop write `i<strlen(arr)` or `i<=strlen(arr)-1` instead of `i<strlen(arr)-1;` because when it print f the value of `i=5` then it decrement `i` by 1 then the value of `i=4` and then it increment the value of `i` by 2 then `i=6` where your condition false which is `i<6`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 for (i = 1; i < strlen(arr); i+=2)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.